# Water leak from water hose or pump - OK to tip machine on side?

Tags: washing-machine

My LG WM3987HW (a front loading washer dryer combo) has developed a leak -- water comes out when the machine is pumping out the waste water. I've removed the top and back panels and can see the area that's getting wet. However, this doesn't seem accessible.

Does anyone know if its safe to tip a washer dryer like this on its side -- this would provide access to the pump and hoses from the bottom.

Comment: what was the problem. I'm seeing the same thing on my WM3987HW.

Comment: Yes it was. Had a repairman fix it

Comment: Yes it was what? What was the problem? Was it the pump, or the hose?

Comment: And, also did you find the water dripping from above the pump compartment. In my case, it seemed like the water was dripping from above onto the pump. But, it was only dripping when the pump was on.

Comment: It was just the hose - he  ordered a new one and replaced it. It was dripping, but only when the pump was on.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly where it was coming from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's fine to tip it on its side. (at least that's what our washing machine repair man did). The water should be drained first.